reinstall gpu drivers from recovery mode
I was trying to install the latest driver from nvidia. Since it wasn't in the additional drivers tab in software and updates, I downloaded it as a .run file on the nvidia website. Then I followed the accepted answer from this question: How do I install the latest NVIDIA drivers from the .run file?
I switched to the noveau driver and did ctrl+alt+f1
sudo su
when I executed sudo service gdm stop I got a blank screen.
I did a hard shutdown and restarted, got to an ubuntu splash screen with "Ctrl+C to stop checking the filesystem". Whether I do Ctrl+C or not, it eventually goes to a blank screen. Doing ctrl+alt+f2 does nothing, all I can do is hard shutdown.
I can get into recovery mode from grub and was trying to follow this answer Help fixing graphics card driver?, but it doesn't find nvidia-current so I'm not sure if it would work in my case.

Does this answer your question? How do I know which NVIDIA driver I need?

I followed this guide and also switched back to the proprietary driver when I was able to access the software & updates window and it reverted back to how it was.
https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-black-screen-solution
Now back to trying to figure out how to update the driver without getting a black screen...
